# Ionic 5 Capacitor project change status bar and navigation bar style and background color

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

for the last 3 weeks I’ve been struggling to edit the status bar text color and navigation background color and actions colors.

I’ve tried a lot of resources, I’ve understood that a lot of plugins are just dead, others just gave me the opportunity to change the the background of the status bar. Plugins were from cordova and capacitor, all those being poorly documented.

I’m aiming to change it on android device, i don’t need an iOS solution. Please help me, I’m really exhausted about it.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5WTA.png)

Comment: Try this in app.component.ts
`const { StatusBar } = Plugins`
`import { Plugins, StatusBarStyle } from '@capacitor/core';`

this.platform.ready().then(() => {
StatusBar.setStyle({
          style: StatusBarStyle.Dark,
        });
        StatusBar.setBackgroundColor({
          color: '#c23346'
        });
});

Comment: I get: Property 'platform' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

Comment: add `public platForm: Platform` in  constructor

Comment: I get: Cannot find name 'Platform'.

Comment: import platform import { Platform} from '@ionic/angular';

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Do you have a solution for changing Navigation bar background?

Comment: Hey, but the status bar changes only when the app is fully loaded, how do i make that the status bar is already #c23346 when the splash screen is on?

Comment: Check this `https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-plugin-navigation-bar-color`

Comment: I don't have a config.xml in my Capacitor project, should I add it?

Comment: you can add by codding like `navigationBarColor.backgroundColorByHexString('#000000');` this

Comment: I get: Error: ./node_modules/ionic-plugin-navigation-bar-color/index.js 75:8-15
"export 'Cordova' was not found in '@ionic-native/core'

Comment: @RaviAshara How do I make the status bar transparent?

Comment: try this `#00000000` Or '#ffffff00'